# c program to find average

Tags: c

i am a beginner in coding ,i am trying to make a program where i input 'n' number of elements in array and find out what percentage of number are positive,negative and zeros.the output is not what i am expecting it is all 'zeros'.Where i input n=3,so the percentage should be .3,.3,.3 when i input numbers one positive,one negative and one zero.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    float per1, per2, per3;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum3 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            int sum1 = sum1 + 1;
        }
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sum3 = sum3 + 1;
        }
    }

    per1 = sum1 / n;
    per2 = sum2 / n;
    per3 = sum3 / n;
    printf("%.6f\n%.6f\n%.6f\n", per1, per2, per3);

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
3
1
-2
0
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

the last three numbers should be .3,.3,.3 but it is giving zeros.

Comment: `sum1/n` takes place in *integer arithmetic*. Google it. Lots of duplicates on this, once you know the search term.

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: "percentage" ..

Comment: @manni66 because syntax of c and c++ is almost similar.

Comment: you need to a floating point arithmetic to get the actual percentages.

Comment: Why `#include <math.h>`? Also, C and C++ are not at all the same language.

Comment: @manni66 Because that's how it is often presented in mainstream - C/C++ And maybe he doesn't even know the difference yet.

Comment: yes, i just started coding.i hardly know the difference.lol

Comment: @anku: no, C and C++ are distinct languages.

Comment: Note that code should be checking the return value from the call to `scanf()` (returns the number of successful assignments). What happens if the user enters non-numeric or otherwise malformed input?

Comment: Always (\*) prefer `double` when using floating-point values. *(\* yes, always)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is a little bit better. I've used the function `malloc()` instead of the "scattered" declaration `int arr[n]` (in this case I prefer the old C style).

People already said you the problem relevant to the variable types and some ways to solve the problem. Here there's another way similar to the others you just saw between the answers.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define STR_ORD_SUFFIX(i) (i>3)?"th":(i==0)?"--":(i==1)?"st":(i==2)?"nd":"rd"

int main()
{
    int n, *arr=NULL;
    float per1,per2,per3;

    int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    int sum3=0;

    printf("How many number you have to insert? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n<=0)
        return 1;

    arr=malloc(n*sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr==NULL)
        return 2;

    printf("Insert %d number%c\n",n,(n!=1)?'s':'\x0');
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%4d%s: ",i+1,STR_ORD_SUFFIX(i+1));
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]<0){
            sum1=sum1+1;
        } else if(arr[i]>0){
            sum2=sum2+1;
        } else {
            sum3=sum3+1;
        }
    }

    per1=sum1; per1/=n; per1*=100.0;
    per2=sum2; per2/=n; per2*=100.0;
    per3=sum3; per3/=n; per3*=100.0;

    printf("\n<0 %.6f%%\n>0 %.6f%%\n=0 %.6f%%\n",per1,per2,per3);

    if (arr!=NULL)
        free(arr);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do floating point arithmetic like this

```
per1=sum1/(1.0*n); 
per2=sum2/(1.0*n);
per3=sum3/(1.0*n);
```

Comment: To explain: by using the floating point value `1.0`, the compiler is now forced to do all calaculations here in floating point arithmetic. A more clear way would be: `sum1/(double)n; `

Answer (score 0):

How do you calculate percentage of some value? Your answers shouldn't be 1,1,1 but 33%, 33%, 33% for input you have. So your code should instead of this

```
per1=sum1/n;
```

be like this

```
per1=sum1*100.0/n;
```

And you have also got wrong your if conditions. The else part is tied only to second if. So every number less or equal to 0 is counted into sum3 which is not what you probably meant. So your

```
 if (arr[i] > 0)
```

should have been

```
 else if (arr[i] > 0)
```

And one last thing. On this line you are creating completely new variable sum1 that will live only to the end of the if statement and thus will not appear in the final calculation. I will leave it to you how to fix it.

```
int sum1 = sum1 + 1;
```

I don't know what environment you are using for development, but you should learn how to use debugger from the beginning. You can then peek into flow of your code to see what is going on and when it went wrong. With simple programs like this it is really easy. If you are on Visual Studio, they have really nice debugger integrated. Just set breakpoint and run Debug. If you are on Linux, there is gdb which might come pretty rough for beginners, but there are also graphical tools like ddd.

Comment: `100.0 * sum1 / n` might work better. You currently round downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `sum1` and `n` are integers, the result of `sum1/n` is also an integer.  This means that if `sum1` is less than `n`, then the result of `sum1 / n` is 0.

To get a floating point result, at least one of the operands has be be `float` or `double`.  I suggest you declare your `sum` variables to be `double` instead of `int`.